How to tell Visual Studio to stop showing me a vulnerability message?
One of the later versions of Visual Studio started showing vulnerability messages.

I looked at the issue - high CPU in certain cases.  It doesn't affect my use case.
How do I get Visual Studio to stop showing me this warning?  I've tried adding the code into the  portion in the csproj, but it persists.

If you do not wish to be notified of vulnerabilities that are less severe than a level you are comfortable with, you can edit the project file and add an MSBuild property NuGetAuditLevel, with value set to low, moderate, high, or critical. For example, <NuGetAuditLevel>high</NuGetAuditLevel> - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1901-nu1904

Also from that page: The initial release of NuGetAudit does not provide a way to suppress specific advisories (URLs). It is a feature we intend on adding based on prioritization of other improvements.
As a mitigation, you can add an appropriate NoWarn to your PackageReference declarations. For example, <PackageReference Include="Contoso.Library" Version="1.0.0" NoWarn="NU1901" />. However, be aware that this will prevent new vulnerabilities of the same severity from being reported to you.

@stuartd It didn't work.  Perhaps because it's a .NET Framework project with old project style.  I also tried <NuGetAudit>false</NuGetAudit> - that didn't work either.

Ah, ok. You might have to just ignore them - I have been getting warnings for months about platform specific code in a package released by MS (looking at you, Cognitive Services!) - it’s annoying seeing them on every build and I don’t like ignoring warnings, but there we are. Or you could just.. upgrade the package and they will go away?

Add the following code to the .csproj file to make the entire project ignore the NU1902 warning:
<PropertyGroup>
  <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU1902</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>


@stuartd's suggestion in comment worked for me (it was only missing nuget restore):

add NoWarn="NU1901" in your PackageReference:

<PackageReference Include="Contoso.Library" Version="1.0.0" NoWarn="NU1901" />


run nuget restore (<-- this step is mandatory otherwise I still had the issue)

I've also tested:
<ItemGroup>
    <NuGetAuditSuppress Include="https://github.com/advisories/XXXX" />
</ItemGroup>

as stated in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/auditing-packages#excluding-advisories
but it did not work.

what worked for me was this.


    <PropertyGroup>
        <NuGetAudit>false</NuGetAudit>
    </PropertyGroup>



